# BindingAdapter not accessible across modules

Tags: android, mobile, android-databinding

I have a project where every feature is its own module.
I have defined some custom data binding `BindingAdapter`s in the main app module, but they are not accessible from the other modules.
I usually get this error: `Cannot find the setter for attribute xxx`

Every module has the `dataBinding{ enabled true }` in their respective gradle files.

If I move the `@BindingAdapter` definition from the core module to the module that needs it, it suddenly works.

I'm using version `3.3.1` of the gradle tools.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

put following in you library module

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`